# how can I test a webservice build with cxf with soap ui?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, soapui

I have method annotated with @WebService, and it should be accessible on a port on my local machine.  How can I use soapui to send a value?

Comment: read the soapui doc. It gives you a place to type in the WSDL URL, it reads the WSDL, then it allows you to construct and send messages.

Comment: It's really easy. Create a new SoapUI project with the WSDL file and rest should be done automatically. It will create sample requests for you and then all you need to do is put data in the request params and click run.

Comment: @bmargulies - I read the doc, it assume I have a WSDL URL.  However I don't have this URL.

Comment: @CoolBeans - Why do you assume I have a WSDL file.  I specify in the question that the webservice was created with a annotation on a class.

Comment: @Guillaume Coté - You still have a WSDL buddy :). There are 2 ways to create a SOAP webservice - contract first and code first. You did code first which means the WSDL was generated by CXF. You should be able to locate it (hint: you just need to add a special thing to your webservice url).

Comment: Just add ?wsdl to the end of the URL for the service endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new project passing the url of your service follow by `?wsdl` in soapui.